# absolute element in carousel item goes under the next item

Tags: html, css, owl-carousel

In owl carousel I have a problem with my absolute element(placed in carousel item) with class 'disciription' which goes behind the next item and almost found no way to bring it forward myself so wish you can help me.

a shot of what I want: [image]

```
<div class="owl-carousel topfeatured">
<div class="item">
    <div class="thumb" style="background-image: linear-gradient(-60deg, #fff 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%), url(https://tinys.club/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/1343232_mkt-pm_got_s7_jon_po.jpg);"></div>
    <div class="description">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <div class="thumb" style="background-image: linear-gradient(-60deg, #fff 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%), url(https://tinys.club/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/1343232_mkt-pm_got_s7_jon_po.jpg);"></div>
    <div class="description"></div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <div class="thumb" style="background-image: linear-gradient(-60deg, #fff 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%), url(https://tinys.club/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/1343232_mkt-pm_got_s7_jon_po.jpg);"></div>
    <div class="description"></div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <div class="thumb" style="background-image: linear-gradient(-60deg, #fff 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%), url(https://tinys.club/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/1343232_mkt-pm_got_s7_jon_po.jpg);"></div>
    <div class="description"></div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <div class="thumb" style="background-image: linear-gradient(-60deg, #fff 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%), url(https://tinys.club/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/1343232_mkt-pm_got_s7_jon_po.jpg);"></div>
    <div class="description"></div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <div class="thumb" style="background-image: linear-gradient(-60deg, #fff 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%), url(https://tinys.club/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/1343232_mkt-pm_got_s7_jon_po.jpg);"></div>
    <div class="description"></div>
</div>
```

```
.topfeatured {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 400px;
}
.topfeatured .item {
    position: relative;
    height: 400px;
}
.topfeatured .item .thumb {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    bottom: 0;
    transition: 0.8s ease-in-out all;
}
.topfeatured .item .description {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    height: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    background: #263238;
    bottom: -170px;
    right: -30px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 60px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    transition: 1s ease-in-out;
}
.topfeatured .item:hover .description {
    bottom: 0;
    transition: 0.8s ease-in-out;
}
.topfeatured .item:hover .thumb {
    bottom: 80px;
}
```

here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4653f7xk/3/

Comment: Not a clue of what you're asking to be honest... The item `.description` is in fact in front of the next item and not behind like you're saying..

Comment: Your "items" need a z-index and a position other than static.

Comment: @Crashtor well it is right to left and by next I mean the left item.

Comment: Ok. I see now. Thanks

Comment: @Korgrue give it a try... This wont work

Comment: I did. It is working here: http://jsfiddle.net/gemlarin/4653f7xk/8/

OP needs to adjust the width of his description blocks so that they dont overlap the adjacent column..

Answer (score 1):

### The answer for not updated question

Just remove `right: -30px`. Here is the working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/4653f7xk/4/

Comment: sounds like Im not good with English :)) edited the post and added a shot of what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Add this class to your css in order to give the active slide a higher z-index than the non-active slides.

```
.owl-item.active {
  z-index: 20;
}
```

Then give the .description class the following attributes:

```
.topfeatured .item .description {
    width: calc(100% + 100px);
    padding: 10px 30px;
    height: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    background: #263238;
    bottom: -170px;
    right: -50px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 60px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    transition: 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4653f7xk/10/

Comment: Thanks for your time. its not what i wanted edited and added a shot take a look

Comment: Updated my answer. See the new Fiddle I attached.